# RenderAction calling POST method instead of GET

Tags: asp.net-mvc, renderaction

I have a page Index.aspx

```
<%@ Page Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage" %>
```

which contains

```
<% Html.RenderAction("GetGroups", "Organisation"); %>
```

Now, in my Organisation controller I have two methods - GET and POST, for GetGroups. Ideally, I expect that when Index.aspx is being called for the first time, GET method of GetGroups will be called. Actually, this is what is happening in local and Test environment but in Live the POST method of GetGroups is being called.

I have also read few posts on SO mentioning that the HTTP method is dictated by the parent action. I also checked that the parent action in my case is calling the GET method.

Any leads on this would be really helpful.

Comment: Can you pls post more code to visualise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was related to some other dll not updated on Live server. So, updating that dll on Live fixed the problem.